# Creating many state vectors and saving them in a file

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create m number of matrices, each of which is an n x 1 numpy arrays. Moreover those matrices should have only two nonzero entries in the two rows, all other rows should have 0 as their entries, meaning that matrix number m=1 should have entries m[0,:]=m[1,:]=1, rest elements are 0. And similarly the last matrix m=m should have entries like m[n-1,:]=m[n,:]=1, where rest of the elements in other rows are 0. So for consecutive two matrices, the nonzero elements shift by two rows. And finally, I would like them to be stored into a dictionary or in a file.

What would be a neat way to do this?

Comment: Why not store all `m` column vectors as a single matrix? You could generate this matrix very easily.

Comment: It is not a square matrix. So filling up these two consecutive nonzero entries for each column in a single matrix is confusing me

Comment: It's not super clear what you're trying to do. Can you please post a small sample of your desired "matrices"? Right now, it sounds like you want `m` column vectors, each with `n` rows, where two entries in each column vector are 1 and the rest are 0. Please refer to my answer if that is correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
In [2]: num_rows = 10  # should be divisible by 2

In [3]: np.repeat(np.eye(num_rows // 2), 2, axis=0)
Out[3]:
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

In terms of storage in a file, you can use [`np.save`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`np.load`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).

Note that the default data type for `np.eye` will be `float64`. If you expect your values to be small when you begin integrating or whatever you're planning on doing with your state vectors, I'd recommend setting the data type appropriately (like `np.uint8` for positive integers < 256 for example).